# Plugin development: get_post_meta is not working

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I am trying to retrieve a post meta data using `get_post_meta` inside my plugin, but its not working.

---

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'some_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta',10,2);

function some_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {

   global $woocommerce, $wpdb, $post ;

   //$user_custom_values = get_post_meta( $post->id, '_pallet-id', true);

   update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Pallet ID', $user_custom_values );

}
```

Comment: You need to try **$post->ID** instead of $post->id

Comment: yeah, i tried but still not fetching the values inside my plugin.